# How do I get rid of the mesh or faces inside my cube?

Tags: modeling

How do I get rid of the mesh or faces inside my cube?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may have inadvertently added a 'Subdivision Surface' Modifier. Go to the properties page and open the 'Modifiers' tab (it will show a little blue wrench). With your cube selected, click the 'X' at the far right of the subdivision surface modifier.
Or, simply hit tab to get into Object mode, delete your cube with <kbd>X</kbd> and add a new one.

Comment: Thank You so much Mike, it worked like magic! I searched for a solution at so many places but couldn't find one. God Bless You :).

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help. Also, be sure to accept the answer. That's how folks around here get paid...

Comment: @MikeMetcalf I edited your answer: applied is not the same as added.

Comment: @pycoder, yes, you are technically correct. And, as we all know, that's the best kind of correct. ;-)